# Why circle an airport after takeoff? (SLC particularly)

Tags: airport, takeoff

I left SLC (Salt Lake City) this morning heading to MCO (Orlando). On previous flights, I remember takeoff similar to other airports. We got in the air, gained altitude, and moved to our heading and left.

This time though, we seemed to circle for a while, gaining altitude. I initially assumed it was to gain enough altitude to clear the surrounding mountain. I ruled out equipment problems because we kept climbing.

Pilots who have experience with SLC, is there a certain runway that needs this altitude gain due to the terrain? Would there be another possible reason this happened?

Comment: Did you take off to the south or the north?  There are a couple of departure procedures at KSLC that call for a hold if vectors aren't received in time...

Comment: I don't know which direction.

Comment: I found [this](http://155.178.201.160/d-tpp/1503/SW4TO.PDF) (PDF) after @UnrecognizedFallingObject made his comment. I do see on Page L12 that SLC has some obstacle procedures.

Comment: However, none of the SLC ODPs involve circling (a climb-in-hold, in other words).  Look at IFP (Laughlin/Bullhead Int'l) or CGZ (Casa Grande Muni) in that document for examples of a departure procedure (textual obstacle SID) that has a climb-in-hold.  (There are several others as well: EKO and FLX also have this, for instance.)

Comment: you'll need the charted SIDs for this -- in particular, look at the SALT LAKE TWO and SEVYR ONE charted SIDs (you'll want to look at both the chart and the associated text page).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would assume it was to avoid terrain, traffic and/or the restricted airspace close to the airport, but there is at least one departure procedure from KSLC that calls for a climb in the hold. The [SALT LAKE TWO departure](http://155.178.201.160/d-tpp/1503/00365SALTLAKE_C.PDF) includes this:

> Continue climb in TCH VORTAC holding pattern (hold south, left turn,
>   341° inbound)

And several other departure procedures call for climbing right or left turns; combined with a few ATC vectors that could easily give the impression of circling.

You might try looking for the actual radar track online if you search [flightaware.com](http://flightaware.com/) or a similar site for your flight. That would let you see what track you really flew.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid terrain or obstacles. Admittedly, I don't know specifically which runway I took off from, making it difficult to provide a definitive answer for this specific airport.

Comment: There is a rather large mountain range directly east of the airport.